# Function not firing when desired scroll point is reached

Tags: javascript, scroll, settimeout

I am working on a small piece of a larger application. I am trying to load a `div` (page) when the `div` above has reached a certain point. Although the point is reached successfully, the function that fires afterwards does not work.

Any help would be appreciated. In the function `DisplayManager.prototype.trackingPage`, once the position is reached the function returns `true` and that starts the process to load the next `div` (page).

```
function processScroll()
{
    clearTimeout(trackTimer2);
    trackTimer2 = setTimeout(function()
    {
        //Track the Page   - pagetoload, pageToTrack, direction
        var test = displayManager.trackingPage(nextToLoad.nextToLoad, nextToLoad.page, nextToLoad.direction)
        console.log(test + " test")

        if (test)
        {
            var something = (function()
            {
                return function()
                {
                    if (!executed)
                    {
                        executed = true;
                        // do something
                        console.log("Something running " + " tl: " + nextToLoad.nextToLoad + "  tp: " + nextToLoad.page);
                        // DisplayManager.prototype.loadIt(nextToLoad.nextToLoad, nextToLoad.page);
                        App.service("util").sendEvent("page-change",
                        {
                            current: nextToLoad.nextToLoad,
                            previous: nextToLoad.nextToLoad
                        });
                    }
                };
            })();
            something();
        }
    }, 60);

    DisplayManager.prototype.setIndicatorStatus(false);
}


$('#' + displayManager.getScrollableContentId()).on('scroll.tracker', function(event)
{
    if (!executed)
    {
        clearTimeout(trackTimer);
        trackTimer = setTimeout(
            processScroll();, 200);
    }
});

DisplayManager.prototype.trackingPage = function(pageToLoad, pageToTrack, pageDirection)
{
    var zoom_level = this.getZoom();
    var mainViewHeight = $('#main-view').height();
    var pageTop = $('#page-' + pageToTrack).offset().top;
    var pageHeight = $('#page-' + pageToTrack).height() * zoom_level;
    var pg_bottom = pageHeight + pageTop;
    var variance = 1.2; //Variable need for ipad screen
    if (App.getIsIpad())
    {
        variance = 0.9
    };
    var mv_percentLimitBottom = variance * mainViewHeight;
    var mv_percentLimitTop = 0.0922 * mainViewHeight;
    var holder = {};
    console.log("%%Pg: " + pageToTrack);
    console.log("%%pg_bottom: " + pg_bottom + "<= " + "mv_percentLimitBottom: " + mv_percentLimitBottom);

    if (pageDirection === 'upward')
    {
        if (pageTop >= mv_percentLimitTop)
        {
            DisplayManager.prototype.showLoadIndicator(pageToLoad, pageDirection);

            return true;
        }
    }
}
else if (pageDirection === 'downward')
{
    if (pg_bottom <= mv_percentLimitBottom)
    {
        DisplayManager.prototype.showLoadIndicator(pageToLoad, pageDirection);
        return true;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Tip: You don't need `setTimeout` to track scrolling. In fact, avoid `setTimeout`/`setInterval` where possible.

Comment: Thanks. I added it because the function fired too many times.